# How do you install pry plugins?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, pry

I've read about these great pry plugins (e.g. pry-debugger, pry-stack_explorer), but after nearly 30 minutes of searching, I can't find any documentation on how to *install* them. I've gone to their [github site](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger), the [pry wiki](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki) and read/watched several tutorials, but there's nothing in there about installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every pry plugin that start with `pry-` are auto-loaded. You just need to `gem install pry-name`.

[Here](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Plugins#overview) is the link about plugins(creating plugins too) and exact quote:

> A valid Pry plugin is a gem that has the pry- prefix (such as the
>   pry-doc gem)
>
> If a Pry plugin is installed (i.e a gem with the pry- prefix is
>   installed) it will be loaded automatically when a session starts.

Note: pry has special command `gem-install gem_name`. You should use that command instead of `.gem install gem_name` in order to work. This (pry)command install and(!) reload gem cache.

If that won't work try installing gems from console then running pry.

ps. you can check installed plugins via `pry --installed-plugins`(in console) or in pry just type `help` and it will show you available commands.